# Discord js not sending embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so im working on a bot that shows data from an api.

This is my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(Config.prefix + 'Test')) {
            let uuid;
                axios
                .get("https://api.hypixel.net/player?name=dkdg&key=MYKEY")
                .then((res) => {
                  uuid = res.data.player.uuid;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("ERR:", err)
                })
                if (!uuid) return;
                const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#e0a467')
                    .setTitle('Test')
                    .setDescription("UUID:" + uuid)
                message.channel.send(Embed);
            }
```

The issue here is that the bot doesn't send the embed.
How can i fix this?

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all of the code inside `.then()`, like this:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(Config.prefix + 'Test')) {
                axios
                .get("https://api.hypixel.net/player?name=dkdg&key=MYKEY")
                .then((res) => {
                  let uuid = res.data.player.uuid;

                  if (!uuid) return;
                  const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#e0a467')
                    .setTitle('Test')
                    .setDescription("UUID:" + uuid)
                  message.channel.send(Embed);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("ERR:", err)
                })
            }
```